# Basic jQuery pop with mutiple forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin, jqueryform

I am trying to create a dialog pop-up box with 2 forms inside of it. The pop-up works great, but inside of the dialog I have 2 forms, each with separate actions.

I am using the jQuery Form Plugin, to submit my form and show a response to #showResponse

The problem i'm having is whenever I click either of the forms it loads the first form in the #showResponse, and i'm not exactly sure why....

This is my Javascript Code

```
$(".formFill2").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            target: "#submitResponse",
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
                $("#submitResponse").show('slow');
                $('#submitResponse').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');

            },
            error: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
                alert("Oops... Looks like there has been a problem.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

And this is my HTML inside my Dialog Window.

```
<fieldset><legend>Email this PDF to</legend>
                  <form class="formFill2" name="emailPDF" id="emailPDF" action="classes/class.Post.php?a=notifyForm" method="post">
                    <label for="email1">Email 1</label>
                    <input name="email1" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['myEmail']; ?>"><br />

                    <input type="submit" value="Send Emails">
                  </form>    
                  </fieldset>

                  <fieldset><legend>Fax this PDF to</legend>
                  <form class="formFill2" name="faxPDF" id="faxPDF" action="classes/class.Post.php?a=faxFile" method="post">
                    <label for="faxNumber">Fax #</label>
                    <input name="faxNumber" type="text" ><br />

                    <input type="submit" value="Send Fax">
                  </form>    
                  </fieldset>
```

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speculating a bit here, but it might be a bug in the form validator.

It may be the case that the Validate plugin is using your original CSS selector (`.formFill2`) in order to get the parameter for the submitHandler function.  If they're using something like `get(0)`, then it'll always return the first DOM object discovered by `.formFill2` -- the first form.

If you `console.log` the 'form' parameter that is passed into your `submitHandler`, do you get the right form?

If it's always giving you the first form, you might want to try something like the following:

```
var submitHandler = function(form) {
    //Your submitHandler...
}

$('#emailPDF').validate(submitHandler : submitHandler);
$('#faxPDF').validate(submitHandler : submitHandler);
```